# with the goal being success

Tags: grammar

Could I ask what "with" means here? I didn't undertsnad the bold part. It is so confusing.

> You don't have to be an Olympic swimmer or star musician to experience
>   flow. In order to achieve flow, you must experience an activity as
>   voluntary and enjoyable, and it must require skill and present an
>   achievable challenge, **with the goal being success**. You must feel
>   as though you have control and receive immediate feedback about your
>   performance with room for growth.

Can we say "with" mean "because of" or "as a result of"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, "with" does not mean "because of" or "as a result of." Let me rephrase the sentence so you can easily understand the meaning.

> ...and it must require skill and present an achievable challenge.
>   **The goal of the activity must also be to succeed.**

The "with" in this sentence just means "the goal being success" is an additional requirement of the activity.  In other words, if you want to experience flow, the goal of the activity must be to succeed.  For example, you cannot succeed if the activity is singing in the shower.  There is no way to measure success in that instance.  But you CAN succeed if the activity is performing a song for an audience.  There will be positive or negative feedback, and if the audience enjoys your performance, then you succeeded.

So to make it very simple, the full meaning of the quote you provided is this.

If you want to experience flow:

1. The activity has to be voluntary and enjoyable
2. The activity must require skill
3. You must be able to succeed at the activity.  It must be possible.
4. You must feel like you have control during the activty.
5. You must received immediate feedback after the activity.

---

Other examples using "with the goal"

> He went on StackExchange with the goal of improving his English.
>
> She held a lecture on making friends, with the goal being for each participant to make one new friend that day.
>
> I planned an sports day with the goal being to get more kids interested in playing sports.
>
> She made an account on OkCupid with the goal of finding a boyfriend.

Comment: Thanks @KumaAra. It was so comprehensive explanations. No body could help me understand this bold part. Can we also rephrase it like "with the goal which is to be succeed"?

Comment: I recommend using the two phrases in my examples above: "with the goal of" or "with the goal being."

Comment: "Which is" should be used to introduce a new idea.  In the above sentence, " with the goal being success" is just one idea.  There is no reason to break it up into two ideas.  And if you did break it up into two ideas, you need to make the first half a complete sentence.  "it must require skill and present an achievable challenge, and it must have a goal, which is to succeed."  This is grammatically correct, but sounds very unnatural. There is no reason to break the idea up into two thoughts.  Generally when we speak English we try to say the meaning in the most simple and clear way possible.